# Abstract Classes in Type Script

Tags: typescript

Trying to test out a very simple abstract class implementation in jsfiddle but i am not getting the result back for any of the prints. Do you see any thing not correct here?

https://jsfiddle.net/learningjsfiddle/L5qy08ch/5/

None of the console.log are printing.

Here is the test example

```
console.log('setup');

interface Activatable {
    //ActivateSelf: () => void;
  ActivateSelf(): void;
}

//abstract keyword, abstract classes are allowed to implement interface
//cannot do new AbstractBase, need sub classes to do method implementation same as C#
abstract class AbstractBase implements Activatable {    
  constructor(public name: string){}

  //abstract method, this satisfies the req due to implementing interface
  abstract ActivateSelf(): void;
};

class ArmyBase extends AbstractBase {
    totalSoldiers: number;
  name: string

  constructor(name: string, totalSoldiers: number){
    //extending a class, need to call a super in the constructor
    //this does not change when extending an abstract class
    super(name);
    this.totalSoldiers = totalSoldiers;

    //abstract method
    public ActivateSelf(){
        //console.log(`ArmyBase [${this.name}] has been activated!`);
      console.log('ArmyBase ' + this.name + ' has been activated!'');
    }
  }

};

class NavyBase extends AbstractBase {
    totalShips: number;
  name: string

  constructor(name: string, totalShips: number){
    //extending a class, need to call a super in the constructor
    //this does not change when extending an abstract class
    super(name);
    this.totalShips = totalShips;

    //abstract method
    public ActivateSelf(){
        //console.log(`NavyBase [${this.name}] has been activated!`);
      console.log('NavyBase ' + this.name + ' has been activated!'');
    }
  }

};

console.log('Printing starts');

const army = new ArmyBase("First Army Base", 100);
const navy = new NavyBase("First Navy Base", 3);

const anotherArmy : Activatable = new ArmyBase("Second Army Base", 250);

console.log('Army base', army)
console.log('Another Army Base', anotherArmy)
console.log('Navy Base', navy)

army.ActivateSelf();
anotherArmy.ActivateSelf();
navy.ActivateSelf();
```

Firebug lite is added to the fiddle, in any case you can add via the following link: 
https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with minor modifications as below:

1) Change

```
console.log('ArmyBase ' + this.name + ' has been activated!'');
```

to

```
console.log('ArmyBase ' + this.name + ' has been activated!');
```

2) Change

```
console.log('NavyBase ' + this.name + ' has been activated!'');
```

to

```
console.log('NavyBase ' + this.name + ' has been activated!');
```

3) Moving closing brace for below constructors to proper place:

```
constructor(name: string, totalShips: number)
constructor(name: string, totalSoldiers: number)
```

**Updated code is:**

```
console.log('setup');

interface Activatable {
    //ActivateSelf: () => void;
  ActivateSelf(): void;
}

//abstract keyword, abstract classes are allowed to implement interface
//cannot do new AbstractBase, need sub classes to do method implementation same as C#
abstract class AbstractBase implements Activatable {    
  constructor(public name: string){}

  //abstract method, this satisfies the req due to implementing interface
  abstract ActivateSelf(): void;
};

class ArmyBase extends AbstractBase {
    totalSoldiers: number;
  name: string

  constructor(name: string, totalSoldiers: number){
    //extending a class, need to call a super in the constructor
    //this does not change when extending an abstract class
    super(name);
    this.totalSoldiers = totalSoldiers;
  }

    //abstract method
    public ActivateSelf(){
        //console.log(`ArmyBase [${this.name}] has been activated!`);
      console.log('ArmyBase ' + this.name + ' has been activated!');
    }
  };


class NavyBase extends AbstractBase {
    totalShips: number;
  name: string

  constructor(name: string, totalShips: number){
    //extending a class, need to call a super in the constructor
    //this does not change when extending an abstract class
    super(name);
    this.totalShips = totalShips;
  }

    //abstract method
    public ActivateSelf(){
        //console.log(`NavyBase [${this.name}] has been activated!`);
      console.log('NavyBase ' + this.name + ' has been activated!');
    }
  };

console.log('Printing starts');

const army = new ArmyBase("First Army Base", 100);
const navy = new NavyBase("First Navy Base", 3);

const anotherArmy : Activatable = new ArmyBase("Second Army Base", 250);

console.log('Army base', army)
console.log('Another Army Base', anotherArmy)
console.log('Navy Base', navy)

army.ActivateSelf();
anotherArmy.ActivateSelf();
navy.ActivateSelf();
```

**The console output is:**

```
setup
Printing starts
Army base ArmyBase { name: 'First Army Base', totalSoldiers: 100 }
Another Army Base ArmyBase { name: 'Second Army Base', totalSoldiers: 250 }
Navy Base NavyBase { name: 'First Navy Base', totalShips: 3 }
ArmyBase First Army Base has been activated!
ArmyBase Second Army Base has been activated!
NavyBase First Navy Base has been activated!
```

Comment: I have tried your updated code, i am only getting setup and printing starts messages nothing else. `https://jsfiddle.net/learningjsfiddle/L5qy08ch/33/`

Comment: I have moved this over to vs code, decorated all with `export` and prints are working good.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
console.log('ArmyBase ' + this.name + ' has been activated!'');
```

With

```
console.log('ArmyBase ' + this.name + ' has been activated!');
```

(Same for navyBase -> There are 5 quotes instead of 4)

You can just do this too :

```
console.log(`ArmyBase ${this.name} has been activated!`);
```